# Does the FULLTEXT search in BOOLEAN mode have a default relevance sorting?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I'm a little bit confused. The `BOOLEAN MODE` [returns only binary values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6562478/318765) (0 or 1) per word that was found, but in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html) it says:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body)
    -> AGAINST ('+MySQL -YourSQL' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
+----+-----------------------+-------------------------------------+
| id | title                 | body                                |
+----+-----------------------+-------------------------------------+
|  1 | MySQL Tutorial        | DBMS stands for DataBase ...        |
|  2 | How To Use MySQL Well | After you went through a ...        |
|  3 | Optimizing MySQL      | In this tutorial we will show ...   |
|  4 | 1001 MySQL Tricks     | 1. Never run mysqld as root. 2. ... |
|  6 | MySQL Security        | When configured properly, MySQL ... |
+----+-----------------------+-------------------------------------+
```

> They do not automatically sort rows in order of decreasing relevance.
>   You can see this from the preceding query result: The row with the
>   highest relevance is the one that contains “MySQL” twice, but it is
>   listed last, not first.

This sounds like there is an ascending relevance by default or is the example result accidentally looking like its sorted?

Comment: The normal sort on relevance would put the *most* relevent record first, not last.

Comment: @GordonLinoff It seems you did not read the quote of the documentation. It says "They do not ... sort...". And in `BOOLEAN MODE` there should be no relevance sorting at all, but the documentation confuses me in this point why I asked my question.